# How to stream low latency camera feed to RTMP server

Tags: streaming-video, ffmpeg, raspivid

Are there any optimizations or recommended techniques for streaming a camera feed from a raspberry pi to an RTMP server. Currently I get a 1-2 second lag when I run:

`raspivid -n -t 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 48 -b 600000 -o - | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec copy -an -f flv rtmp://ip-address:1935/app/stream_name`

I'm viewing the stream with openCV and no buffer so I know there is little to no client side delay.